# Tor and stem library : non consistent error message with wrong password

Tags: stem, authentication

I'm writing a little program trying to connect to Tor (v0.2.9.10) using the stem library (v1.5.4).

I've taken inspiration from this page : https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html

For now it looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import getpass
import stem.connection
import stem.socket


if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    controller = stem.control.Controller.from_port()
  except stem.SocketError as exc:
    print("Unable to connect to tor on port 9051: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

  try:
    controller.authenticate()
  except stem.connection.MissingPassword:
    try:
      pw = os.environ['torpassword']
    except KeyError:
      print("Please configure the 'torpassword' environment variable", file=sys.stderr)
      sys.exit(1)

    try:
      controller.authenticate(password = pw)
    except stem.connection.PasswordAuthFailed:
      print("Unable to authenticate, password is incorrect")
      sys.exit(1)
  except stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure as exc:
    print("Unable to authenticate: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

  print("Tor is running version %s" % controller.get_version())
  controller.close()
```

When the right password is given, it works, it displays the Tor version as it's supposed to do.
When there's no password I get the message I'm expecting : Please configure the 'torpassword' environment variable

The problem is when I'm trying with wrong passwords to see how it reacts, but I get different messages everytime and I'm bit confused about that.
For example :

```
[dev@l]#$ torpassword=test ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 28, in <module>
    controller.authenticate(password = pw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/control.py", line 1071, in authenticate
    stem.connection.authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/connection.py", line 618, in authenticate
    raise auth_exc
stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure: Received empty socket content.
[dev@l]$ torpassword=test ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 28, in <module>
    controller.authenticate(password = pw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/control.py", line 1071, in authenticate
    stem.connection.authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/connection.py", line 618, in authenticate
    raise auth_exc
stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[dev@l]$ torpassword=test ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 28, in <module>
    controller.authenticate(password = pw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/control.py", line 1071, in authenticate
    stem.connection.authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/connection.py", line 618, in authenticate
    raise auth_exc
stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[dev@l]$ torpassword=test ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 28, in <module>
    controller.authenticate(password = pw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/control.py", line 1071, in authenticate
    stem.connection.authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/connection.py", line 618, in authenticate
    raise auth_exc
stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[dev@l]$ torpassword=test ./test.py 
Unable to authenticate, password is incorrect
```

In my opinion the last message should be the one I get all the time.
Is it a problem in the Tor server ? Not handling a wrong password the right way ? (not so likely in my opinion)
Is it a problem with the stem library ? (could be, but I doubt it)
Is it a problem with my code ? (much more likely, but I can't see why)

Thanks for your time.
Regards,

#
Edit following canonizing ironize answer :

I did try creating a new controller before the second attempt to authenticate, I did try to use the reconnect method
Finally I tried to only let the second authenticate part alone.
All these produced no effect.

#
Edit 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import getpass
import stem.connection
import stem.socket


if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    controller = stem.control.Controller.from_port()
  except stem.SocketError as exc:
    print("Unable to connect to tor on port 9051: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

  try:
    try:
      controller.authenticate(password = "test")
    except stem.connection.PasswordAuthFailed:
      print("Unable to authenticate, password is incorrect")
      sys.exit(1)
  except stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure as exc:
    print("Unable to authenticate: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

  print("Tor is running version %s" % controller.get_version())
  controller.close()
```

Even a simpler piece of code like this one, with an obvious wrong password show different results when called.

```
[dev@l]$ ./test2.py 
Unable to authenticate: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
Exception in thread Event Notifier (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 811, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 764, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/control.py", line 958, in _event_loop
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 621, in wait
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 332, in wait
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[dev@l]$ ./test2.py 
Unable to authenticate: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[dev@l]$ ./test2.py 
Unable to authenticate: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[dev@l]$ ./test2.py 
Unable to authenticate: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[dev@l]$ ./test2.py 
Unable to authenticate: Received empty socket content.
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, it does seem that I was wrong. There *may* be a bug in stem itself. Although I can't actually reproduce the same one you're seeing. What version of stem are you running?

Comment: Actually your answer was interesting. As stated in my post the versions are :  Tor (v0.2.9.10) using the stem library (v1.5.4)

Comment: I edited with a simpler piece of code and the result.

Comment: I think there is a race condition in the thread that's handling the control connection...

Comment: Actually I'm rather a newbie at Python. Should a bug be reported somewhere ? And by the way, can you reproduce it yourself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the stem library that is the cause of this issue, I reported it there : https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/22679